# Why does adding material implication as an axiom to propositional calculus make every formula provable?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've made it to section 12 in Kleene's Mathematical Logic, which is about completeness. Surprisingly, I was able to understand how every valid formula is provable. However, one of the exercises he gives (12.4) is to show that every formula is provable after adding $A \supset B$ to the axioms of the propositional calculus. I understand that adding this axiom kind of breaks everything down, because it makes the deduction theorem a moot point. I've had a bit of trouble formalizing my thoughts though.

One of the theorems (theorem 10) says that if  $\vdash A\supset B$, then $A \vdash B$. However, if $A \supset B$ is an axiom, then the hypothesis is always true and B is always provable. Is this all that's required to show that introducing implication as an axiom makes every formula provable? It seems right in my mind, but also "too easy," so I just wanted to get some verification.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's basically it. To show that $B$ is provable, take for $A$ some true statement $\top$. Then $\top\vdash B$, so $\vdash B$.

Comment: What you've said is correct, but I don't think that's what he/she said in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

" However, if A⊃B is an axiom, then the hypothesis is always true and B is always provable."

That doesn't hold.  (A⊃B) can be an axiom, but the hypothesis "A" is not always true.  So that won't work.

But, let's say that (A⊃B) is our only axiom, and we have the rule of substitution.  What can you do then?

Let x/y indicate that formula "x" gets substituted with formula "y".  Then, we could write a proof like this:

```
axiom              1 (A⊃B)
1 A/(A⊃B)          2 ((A⊃B)⊃B)
2, 1 modus ponens  3 B
```

Notice that deriving B here is not affected by the substitution made in the axiom.  We could write another proof like this:

```
axiom             1 (A⊃B)
1 B/C             2 (A⊃C)
2 A/(A⊃B)         3 ((A⊃B)⊃C)
3, 1 modus ponens 4 C
```

Since C is arbitrary, it follows that we could get any formula given (A⊃B) as an axiom.

This shows that modus ponens would break down if (A⊃B) were an axiom.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest the following approach, recalling that the new axiom :

> $\vdash A \rightarrow B$

is an *axiom schema*.

If we add it , we can use in derivations every *instance* of it.

Thus, we can have :

$\vdash \lnot P \rightarrow Q$

and also :

$\vdash \lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q$.

Now we can use them with axiom n°7, page 16 :

> > $\vdash (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow \lnot B) \rightarrow \lnot A)$

to derive, by *modus ponens* twice :

$\vdash \lnot \lnot P$.

Then apply axiom n°8, page 16 :

> > $\vdash \lnot \lnot A \rightarrow A$

to conclude with :

> > $\vdash P$.

But $P$ is a formula whatever; thus, the addition of the new axiom licenses us to prove **every** formula, and the system is now *inconsistent*.

---

The issue does not involve specifically the *Deduction Theorem*.

We can destroy consistency of *propositional calculus* adding as axiom a formula $A$ whatever which is not a *tautology* (and thus : $\nvdash A$).

If we consider, instead of $A \rightarrow B$, a new formula : $A \lor B$, adding it as a new axiom produces the same result.

Substitute $P$ for both $A$ and $B$ and we have : $\vdash P \lor P$, which implies $\vdash P$.

Then we do the same with $\lnot P$ and we have : $\vdash \lnot P$.

*Conclusion* : *propositional calculus* plus the axiom $\vdash A \lor B$ is *inconsistent*.

Comment: "Substitute ¬P for both A and B and we have : ⊢P∨P, which implies ⊢P."  I think there's a typo there.